# Auto logon undesirable and need to remove it

Tags: windows-7, windows

via microsoft software and without realizing what I was doing, I established an auto logon for access to facebook and comcast email.  How do I remove it now?

Answer (score 0):

This auto-login info is saved in your browser, so clearing it depends on which browser you're using.

In firefox you can go to history > clear recent history. Pushing alt with firefox selected will pull up the bar at the top where you can find this history tab.

For chrome you can reference to this link - https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/vjeLBFNuUoU

Answer (score 0):

To stop the Auto login of websites, (assuming you are using Internet Explorer) go to the windows control panel, then Internet Options, Content, 'Autocomplete settings' button, then turn off the saved passwords by unchecking the last two checkboxes then click on 'Delete Autocomplete History' button. Close and restart Internet Explorer.